# Smart Gwt List Grid:How to check selected records

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using smart gwt 2.5 List grid.
In this I am using check box for simple selection.below is the code for that:

```
    getGrid().setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
        getGrid().setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
```

I am using data source for the list grid.For feeding data  calling this method:

```
 public void setTestData(DataClass[] testData) {
    setAttribute("testData", testData, true);
}
```

My grid is rendering data properly.Now I want to set checked some of records (Row) depending in some condition.Lets say I want row number 1 and 5 should be checked.

For this after feeding data to data source I write code like below to check data:

```
    getGrid().selectRecord(1);` 
    getGrid().selectRecord(5);
```

But is not doing any checked operations to check box.I am not getting at what point I am doing mistake.
same thing when I tried with out data source and I feed data to list grid simply by setdata It was working.
Please help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: Any other method to select records are also not working.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a DataSource, including a clientOnly DataSource, fetching data is asynchronous, so your selectRecord() calls are happening when data is not loaded yet.  Wait for DataArrived before attempting to select records.

Comment: Data for grid is loaded already.After that I test my condition to check the record.

Comment: The data may be loaded in the browser and present in the clientOnly DataSource, but the operation for the grid to fetch from the clientOnly DataSource is still asynchronous, even though the data is present in the browser.  You don't need a workaround, you just need to use DataArrived to wait for data to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

One work around which is working for me is that:
I removed selection appearance and selected type from my grid and took a column for check box 
like below:

```
    NTListGridField customCheckBoxField = new NTListGridField("select", "Select", 25);
        customCheckBoxField.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);
        customCheckBoxField.setType(ListGridFieldType.BOOLEAN);
        customCheckBoxField.setCanFilter(false);
        customCheckBoxField.setCanEdit(true);
        customCheckBoxField.setCanToggle(true);
```

Now for selecting records,

```
record.setAttribute("select", true);
```

Comment: This is not a necessary workaround, nor would it correct the problem noted above; most likely this workaround was attempted at the same time as other code changes, which actually fixed the problem.